# testing form validation using Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I'm trying to test if the error shows up on the screen when user submit the form with empty inputs!

I did this test and everything looks good to me ,but it says that length is 0 which means it didn't show up, where is my mistake ?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { login } from '../../../services/account-service';
import validate from '../../../utility/login-validate';
import { Button, Error, Form, Input, Label, NavLink, Sign, SignBtn } from './signin-style';

/**
 * Component to log in the website if you have valid information, and display errors if the information is invalid.
 */
function Signin() {
  const [email, setemail] = useState('');
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState(null);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  /**
   *this methode called when the user presses the submit button, first it will check if there is errors, if not it will submit the form!
   *
   * @param {React.SyntheticEvent} event click on submit button event!
   */
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    /**
     * Function that check if the user inserted wrong information and put it on `error` variable!, then it will update the 'errors' state!
     */
    const error = validate(email, password);
    setErrors(error);

    await login(email, password);
  };

  /**
   * Method that handle the change on { email input } by taking the input value and setting it on 'email' state!
   *
   * @param {React.SyntheticEvent} event when user type in email input!
   */
  const handleemailChange = (event) => {
    const user = event.currentTarget.value;
    setemail(user);
  };

  /**
   *  Method that handle the change on { password input } by taking the input value and setting it on 'password' state!
   *
   * @param {React.SyntheticEvent} event  When user type in password input
   */
  const handlePasswordChange = (event) => {
    const pass = event.currentTarget.value;
    setPassword(pass);
  };

  return (
    <Sign>
      <h1>Sign In</h1>
      <NavLink to="/login">Need an account?</NavLink>
      {errors ? <Error id="error">* Invalid email or password!</Error> : null}
      <Form>
        <div>
          <Label htmlFor="email">
            <Input
              id="email"
              onChange={handleemailChange}
              placeholder="Email"
              type="text"
              value={email}
            />
          </Label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Label htmlFor="password">
            <Input
              id="password"
              onChange={handlePasswordChange}
              placeholder="Password"
              type="password"
              value={password}
            />
          </Label>
        </div>
        <SignBtn>
          <Button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
            Sign in
          </Button>
        </SignBtn>
      </Form>
    </Sign>
  );
}

export default Signin;
```

my test :

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import '../../../setup-tests';
import Signin from './Signin';

describe('Signin component', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Signin />);
  });

  it('should display error on the screen on click', () => {
    const emailInput = wrapper.find('#email');
    const passwordInput = wrapper.find('#password');

    passwordInput.simulate('change', { currentTarget: { value: '' } });
    emailInput.simulate('change', { currentTarget: { value: '' } });

    const submitButton = wrapper.find('[type="submit"]');
    submitButton.simulate('click');

    expect(wrapper.find('#error')).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

test return this when I run it :

Expected length: 1,
Received length: 0,
Received object: {}

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you have a html form, not just an arbitrary submit function. Try identifying the form, eg. `<Form id='form'>` and testing it like so:

```
const form = wrapper.find('#form').at(0);
form.simulate('submit');
```

**edit**
You can also try:

```
        wrapper.update();

        setTimeout(function () {
            expect(...).toBe(...);
            done();
        }, 500);
```

and don't forget to pass `done` as your test case function's argument.

Comment: didn't work, If you have this component with empty test file how would you test the submit button ?

Comment: I've added an edit. Sorry, but I don't understand your question.